How to add claims to token using PowerShell
I have a transversal API that should be used by different business applications through an APIM that contains a validate token policy and therefore I need to generate a token for testing the APIM.
I'm struggling to add claims to token, here is what I tried:
$tenantId = "****" 
$clientId = "****" 
$secret = "****" 
$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$claims = @{
    "access_token" = @{
        "role" = "arole"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body =  @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = $scope
    Client_Id     = $clientId
    Client_Secret = $secret
    claims        = $claims
}

$connection = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Body $body
$token = $connection.access_token
 
$token

This code return the following error and it works well without the claims part:

Edit to add error message as text instead of image:
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS901001: Invalid request. The claims request parameter value 'System.Collections.Hashtable' is invalid. Trace ID: da35dc46-7e9f-4a0d-a318-2dd7dc456d00 Correlation
ID: ca7aecf2-ee32-4d38-80c7-cda0e9e07394 Timestamp: 2024-10-24 19:00:01Z","error_codes":[901001],"timestamp":"2024-10-24
19:00:01Z","trace_id":"da35dc46-7e9f-4a0d-a318-2dd7dc456d00","correlation_id":"ca7aecf2-ee32-4d38-80c7-cda0e9e07394"}
At line:20 char:15
+ ... onnection = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Body  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand


if possible, please copy and past the error message as well. It makes much easier for people to search it and read it.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but the code attached seems to be requesting an access token. The claims included in that access token is not controlled by what you input in your POST request, but rather controlled by the Application Registration in AzureAD/Entra ID.
I belive you need to add optional claims to your token as per the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/optional-claims?tabs=appui
The returned token will then contain these additional claims. Perhaps you can share a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Skip | ConvertTo-Json -Compress - otherwise you end up with an escaped JSON document embedded in a string when Invoke-RestMethod converts the whole body to JSON

@sirtao I update the question and added the error as text

@MathiasR.Jessen I tried without "| ConvertTo-Json -Compress" the result is the error I added in the Edit part of the question.

@MarcH I updated the question to add more info about the reason why I need to generate the token.
